# How to generate pdf file for multiple image.?

Tags: visualforce

My requirement is i have a visualforce page in which select multiple image in any format and then upload it and generate one pdf file for all selected image. How it is possible in salesfore using apex or visualforce page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `renderAs="pdf"` in apex:page.
Refer: [Salesforce renderAs="pdf" documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Formating-VisualForce-Page-rendered-as-PDF-1327108686696&language=en_US)